# unable to execute matplotlib in Jupyter Notebook 6

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter

I'm fairly new at programming/python. I’ve tried to install python (3.8 and the 3.7 win32) on an older system – win 10Home /w/4Gb ram. The problem is I couldn’t get matplotlib to run. I decided to uninstall python and install Jupyter Notebook 6.0.3 win32 – no problem with the install but I still can’t run matplotlib to executed the following: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt. Below is the following error message:

```
OSError Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in <module>   
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in <module>
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
~\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: It looks like your numpy installation is broken as well.  The thing that makes me very suspicious is that the site-packages are in 'Roaming', but your python installation is not.  I suggest uninstall everything and start with a fresh anaconda installation.

Comment: Thanks much, will take your advise and reinstall.